# How can I run the Couchdb test suite as mentioned in the Getting Started section of the tour?

Tags: couchdb

This may be a very strange and/or dumb question, but I'm trying to follow along with the [Couchd Documentation Getting Started section](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/tour.html#) paragraph [1.4.2](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/tour.html#welcome-to-futon) describes running the test suite:

> Navigate to the test suite by clicking “Test Suite” on the Futon sidebar, then click “run all” at the top to kick things off.

In the screenshot and on my instance running locally I can't seem to find the mentioned "Test Suite" in the Futon sidebar.

How can I run the Test Suite through another means?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the source of Futon, I found these comments in the menu where the item should be:

```
<!-- These tests are run during installation, so this link is disabled by default. -->
<!-- <li><a href="couch_tests.html?script/couch_tests.js">Test Suite</a></li> -->
```

So I guess the manual is outdated (I have CouchDB 1.5.0 installed).

Here is the link if you want to run them anyway:
`http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/couch_tests.html?script/couch_tests.js`